# Jquery with Struts

Tags: jquery, struts2

Can we use a jquery function directly in struts like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
....................
...........
});
```

or do we have to follow the standard by using jquery.jar. I searched on google for an example and tutorial but couldn't find one.

Comment: what u mean? in the jsp file, yes. you have specific your question

Comment: Please use jQuery like you would in any web project, you don't need the jar and it encourages the use of custom jQuery tags which obfuscate the resulting jquery, so when you ask people what is happening no one know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as the way you want,though there is a plugin with Jquery and if you want to use that plugin, you need to add that jar in your class-path but if you want to use Jquery independently you can use that.

I have used this successfully is many projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly use it, provided you have added the struts2-jQuery jar in your build-path and have used `<sj:head />` tag in your JSP under HTML `<head>` tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

and the below code under head tag.

```
<head>
<title>MY TITLE</title>
<sj:head />
</head>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. You can put this either in your .html or .jsp
First you will need to import like in the code and then use the API.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```